# Expression Blend 3d model examples

Tags: xaml, expression-blend

I'm going to create some 3d object for Silverlight with XAML. I want to use Expression Blend for this. It isn't new tool but I can't find any examples of 3d model in Expression Blend. I don't mention cube and other simple object I mean something complex. Does it mean that I need to look on XNA for creating something real cute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression Blend isn't really the right tool for this. For complex shapes, have a designer build them out in Maya/3DS/whatever, then use a tool like [Zam3D](http://www.erain.com/products/zam3d/DefaultPDC.asp) to convert them to xaml.

Comment: You are right, I've found Zam3D tool too. It looks very nice and I can create 3D object there. But I can't find a lot of samples of models for this.